# menu dropdown not showing correctly on mobile

Tags: css, drupal, responsive-design

I have a drupal site. It is responsive. 
On mobile the regular menu should show in a drop down. However, when you click navigation, the menu tabs appear in the inspect element but on the screen it is just a plain blue box, you can't see the links.

The site is [`http://jspca.org.il/`](http://jspca.org.il)

```
<ul class="menu" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/en" title="" class="active">Home</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/en/content/about-us" title="About Us">About</a></li>
<li class="expanded"><a href="/en/content/adoption">Adoption</a><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/en/content/policy" title="">Policy</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/en/content/contract" title="">Contract</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/en/dogs" title="">Adopt a Dog</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/en/Cats" title="">Adopt a Cat</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a href="/en/virtual-adoption" title="">Virtual Adoption</a></li>
</ul><span class="drop-down-toggle"><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span></span></li>
<li class="expanded"><a href="/en/content/volunteer" title="Volunteer">Volunteer</a><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a href="/en/content/shelter">Shelter</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/en/content/volunteer-clinic">Volunteer at the Clinic</a></li>
```

---

```
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 440px) {

  .top_left, 
  .top_right,
  .search_block,
  .region-user-menu{ width: 100% !important; }

  #logo { text-align: center; width: 100%; }

  #site-title{ width: 100%; }

  #site-title a{ width: 100%; text-align: center; float:none; /* EMS */}

  .social-icons{ position: inherit; width: 100%; }

  .social-icons ul{ text-align: center; }

  .top_right .region-user-menu ul.menu{ float: none; }

  .block-menu ul{ float: none; text-align: center; }
}
```

It looks like the `style="overflow: hidden; display: block;"` is being added by a js file, it only appears on mobile. 
I have a js script that is being called:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.nav-toggle').click(function() {
    $('#main-menu div ul:first-child').slideToggle(250);
    return false;
  });
  if( ($(window).width() > 640) || ($(document).width() > 640) ) {
      $('#main-menu li').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).children('ul').css('display', 'none').stop(true, true).slideToggle(250).css('display', 'block').children('ul').css('display', 'none');
      });
      $('#main-menu li').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut(250).css('display', 'block');
      })
        } else {
    $('#main-menu li').each(function() {
      if($(this).children('ul').length)
        $(this).append('<span class="drop-down-toggle"><span class="drop-down-arrow"></span></span>');
    });
    $('.drop-down-toggle').click(function() {
      $(this).parent().children('ul').slideToggle(250);
    });
  }

});
```

is this causing the issue? How do I adapt it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old jquery version "v1.5.2". 
Apparently there is a [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12630) in old versions. 
Best solution would be to change the version to a more updated one. If you can't do then fix you css as below

```
.menu{ overflow:visible!important; }
```

remember to add it only to small screen using @media

another solution is to do the same as above but via JS. Add the line below

```
$('.menu').attr("style","overflow:visible");
```

right after

```
$('#main-menu div ul:first-child').slideToggle(250);
```

Comment: I think the overflow:hidden is being added by javascript. It only apprears on mobile. I've edited the question above to show the javascript. How do I remove it?

Comment: Hi LTech I edited my answer above, Hope it will help.